# Rails 3 - How do I test a controller module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testunit

I have 3 controllers which include the same module.

How can I test with Test:Unit the module in one place ?

Should I write 3 identical functional tests for each controller (not DRY) ?

TestController / TestController1 / TestController2 :

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
 include TestModule

 test_module :test, :only => [:index]
 ...
end
```

TestModule :

```
module TestModule
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

 module ClassMethods
  private

  def test_module(resource, options = {})
   self.before_filter(options.slice(:only, :except)) do
     puts 'test_module'
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Controller tests should test exactly that... the controller.  So any tests you're writing for the controller should verify that the controller actions do exactly what you expect, regardless of what modules you have included for them to do what they do.  Consider them as a black box, all you care about are giving the controller some inputs and then verifying the outputs are what they should be.

You should test the module as it's own entity, writing mock-ups and tests to verify each module method sufficiently.  Your controllers may change in the future, so this way you will always have test coverage for the module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will write tests for my controllers. But how write isolated tests (with Test:Unit) for my module ? I have to mock a controller ? If so where should I put these tests, and so on ?

Comment: Think of it this way: Writing a test for a module is sort of like writing a test for a Model.  They both just have methods inside of them.  So when you call or pass parameters into a method, you expect a certain result out of the method and that is what you should be testing in the modules.  So if I called `TestModule.create_something_amazing` and expect it to create something amazing for me, then the tests should verify that it does what I expect.  These tests should go in the `Unit/lib` folder since your module should have been placed in the `lib` directory of your Rails app by convention

Comment: I did test my models modules like you said. But I don't understand how to test this specific module. Because it's a class method of a controller. I need somehow the controller instance to verify the integrity of it, and I don't understand how I can do that. I can't just call the test_module method in a unit test, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You might want to learn to use standard tools such as RSpec for testing controllers.

Here's the link to [Ryan Bates' Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec)

Comment: Well I know how to test a controller, in this case I just want to figure out how to write an isolated test for this controller module.